# Need powershell script to check if users are still in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory, duosecurity

I have a CSV file I downloaded from my company's Duo Admin Portal of over 4k "Inactive Users".

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that I can export the results as such:

- For users found still in Active Directory = User - Email - Enabled
- For users not found in Active Directory = User " not found."

The closest code that I have come up with is:

```
$InputFile = C:\Users\name\desktop\TestingSample1.csv
$CheckADUser = Import-CSV $InputFile | ForEachObject {GetADUser -f "samAccountName -eq $($_.)"}
$OutputFile = C:\Users\name\desktop\DuoInactiveUser.csv

$Result = 
if ($CheckADUser -ne $null) {
-Properties samAccountName,mail,enabled | select @{name= '$DuoInactiveUsers.Username';expression= {$_.samAccountName}},@{name= '$DuoInactiveUsers.Email';expression={$_.mail}},@{name= 'DuoInactiveUsers.Enabled';expression={$_.Enabled}}}
else {
@{name= 'DuoInactiveUsers.Username';expression="{$_.samAccountName} not found!"

$Result | Export-CSV $OutputFile -Append
```

The problems I am running into are:

1. Not all listed user names in the exported CSV, are in the samAccountName format. Some are in logon name format.
2. I keep getting the error "ObjectNotFound: ((name):ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException" instead of producing the else statement.

I have tried looking up the error for ways to fix the issue, and found a few options, but none of them appear to be working.

I have tried to catch the error but I do not have the permissions with my work profile to add PowerShell modules that I have found elsewhere that are supposed to work.

Comment: Whats the column name (header) of your Csv having the users ?

Comment: the header column of the input file where the users are being pulled from is "Username".

Comment: I see, and, can you clarify on what you mean by "Not all listed user names in the exported CSV, are in the samAccountName format. Some are in logon name format." ? the logon name IS the samAccountName. Do you mean some rows have a userPrincipalName instead of a SAM?

Comment: "the logon name IS the samAccountName. Do you mean some rows have a userPrincipalName instead of a SAM? "
I am sorry for the confusion my mislabeling caused. The names in the "Username" Column are either samAccountName or userPrincipleName format.

Comment: gotcha, just saw this, remember if you want someone to see your response in a comment, you can @ them i.e. @Santiago would make me see the notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code has many syntax errors, leaving that aside, if your CSV values can have `samAccountName` or `UserPrincipalName` you can change your filter to target both possibilities. I added some inline comments to help you follow the logic of the code. An important thing to note, it seems like you're trying to have dynamic properties depending on if the user was found or not, this is not possible with `Export-Csv`, you must create uniform objects (objects that will have the same structure, same property names) otherwise you will lose data.

```bash
$InputFile = 'C:\Users\name\desktop\TestingSample1.csv'
Import-Csv $InputFile | ForEach-Object {
    $value = $_.Username
    # if the CSV has an empty value here,
    if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($value)) {
        # this is the only way to make the LDAPFilter throw an error
        # we must skip, go next..
        return
    }

    $getADUserSplat = @{
        LDAPFilter = "(|(samAccountName=$value)(userPrincipalName=$value))"
        Properties = 'mail'
    }

    $user = Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat
    $samAccountName = $user.samAccountName
    $status = 'Found'

    # if the user was not found in AD
    if (-not $user) {
        # use the value we have from the CSV here
        $samAccountName = $_.Username
        $status = 'Not Found'
    }

    # `$user.Enabled` and `$user.Mail` will be null if the user was not found
    # we don't need to worry about those

    [pscustomobject]@{
        SamAccountName = $samAccountName
        Status         = $status
        Enabled        = $user.Enabled
        Mail           = $user.Mail
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\name\desktop\DuoInactiveUser.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: @RichardDiring glad it did, you can consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) then